# Passing array from a function to another function

Tags: php

I have an array ,$idarray .

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "102"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "211"
  [2]=>
  string(4) "421"
}
```

Call the other function an pass the array element.

```
foreach($idarray as $id){
$r = get_rate($id);
  foreach($r as $result=> $row){
  }
}
```

Another function

```
function get_rate($qid){
foreach($qids as $qid){
execute sql here
}
```

Error occur when i pass the array to the function "foreach($qids as $qid)" , then I cannot 
go into the foreach statement and do the execution.
How can I pass an array to the function ?

Comment: `$r = get_rate($id);` here you are passing an array element not an array!!

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($idarray as $id){
  $r = get_rate($id);
  ...
```

passes a string, not an array. As you can see - your array contain strings, not arrays. It is not a multidimensional array. Using a string as it were an array will produce the error. Therefore :

```
function get_rate($qid){
   foreach($qids as $qid){
     execute sql here
   }
}
```

should be

```
function get_rate($qid){
   execute sql here, you already have a single id, $qid
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($idarray as $id){
$r = get_rate($id);//here $id is an array element not an array
  foreach($r as $result=> $row){
  }
}
```

Another function

```
    function get_rate($qid){
      //here $qid is a single element like 102,211,so on.....
//no need foreach loop here,just execute your sql and return your result
    //foreach($qids as $qid){
    execute sql here
    //}
}
```

Comment: in this case it can get_rate for once , how about the other two ?how to execute?

Comment: If you run this code :
$idarray = array(101,102,103,104);

foreach($idarray as $id){
$r = get_rate($id); 
}

function get_rate($qid){
echo 'Id:'.$qid.',';
}
you output will be like that:Id:101,Id:102,Id:103,Id:104,